# How do I create a Typography component that can be used as h1, h2, h3, h4..etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, styled-components

How can I create a Typography component, which can be reused with all title tags, h1, h2, h3..etc.

In the ideal world I thought of the code below, but I still haven't found in the documentation how to write it correctly.

```
export const Typography = (level) => styled(level)`
..style here
`;
```

h1:

```
<Typography level={h1}>Text here</Typography>
```

Is there any way to reproduce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one complete solution that I think very closely matches your question.

Uses dynamic tag names (like other answer) and includes a styled-component that represents your `Typography` component. I named it `StyledHeader` since it really is only about the header.

A broader use would allow any tag to be sent through the same code to apply typography to any element. I'l let you expand upon this.

A working example: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2hnzvh?file=src%2FApp.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Header = ({tagName, ...otherProps}) =>  {
  const Tag = tagName;
  const defaultProps = {
    tagName: 'div'
  };

    return <Tag {...otherProps}/>
}


const StyledHeader = styled(Header)`
  font-style: italic;
`; 


export default function App() {
  const headers = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
  const output = headers.map(header =>
      <StyledHeader tagName={header}>Content</StyledHeader>
  );

  return (
    <div>
    {output}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand in your code, where the h1 h2 h3 semantic tag comes in

Comment: You said this: "_which can be reused with all title tags, h1, h2, h3..etc_" - I was just demonstrating that you can pass any of the header tags and style them. Wasn't that your question? How can I apply typography to the header tags?

Comment: Yes, you are not wrong, but the question is ... if I can use it the way I did in the example. I wanted something simple, just that it is dynamic tag in styled-components.

Comment: That's why I gave you a complete solution - this is about as easy as it gets (for a complete solution).

Comment: Very good, I managed to apply within my global here, thank you very much.

Comment: Yesterday your code worked, today I got this error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Heading`.

Comment: I can't peer into your environment for you. So I'm not clear how I can help you. Perhaps ask a new question with some details about the changes you've made from this answer. I"m certain I, or someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use ejs. And write code like this:

`<% if(parameter == 'true'){ %>`

`<h1>some text</h1>`

`<% } %>`

`<% if(parameter2 == 'true'){ %>`

`<h2>text2</h2>`

`<% } %>`

In js file it will look like:

`render('filename.ejs',{parameter: true, parameter2: false})`

I think it will work for small project, for something bigger you will need to find better solution.

Comment: The idea is good, but I wanted to use styled components, even to be reused in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use common tags you can use simple construction like this:

```
const styleMap={
  "h1":{
    margin: '40px',
    border: '5px solid pink'
  },
...
}
export const Typography=({Tag, children, ...otherProps})=>{
return  <Tag {...otherProps} style={styleMap[Tag]}>{children}</Tag>
}
```

Or variant with class styling:

```
import './styles.css'

const styleMap={
  h1:'h1_styled',
...
}
export const Typography = ({ Tag, children, ...otherProps }) = {
  return React.createElement(
    Tag || 'div', 
    {...otherProps, style:styleMap[Tag]}, 
    children
  );
}
```

For more complex tasks just consider [ready-made solutions](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/) or their [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Typography/Typography.js)

Comment: The idea is good, but I wanted to use styled components, even to be reused in other projects.

Comment: i add simple styling